# Perpendicular vector from $(\cos(\theta)x, \sin(\theta)x)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Hi  want to know how to compute a perpendicular vector from a vector that contains non-integer-- for example if my vector is like $(cos(\theta)x, sin(\theta)x)$, is it possible to compute one vector that is perpendicular to it?

Answer (score 7):

In 2 dimensions, $(a,b)$ and $(-b, a)$ (or $(b, -a)$) are perpendicular. You can check it with the dot product:
$$(a, b) \cdot (-b, a)=a*(-b)+b*a=-ab+ba=0$$

Comment: after finding the perpendicular vector, can we add the perpendicular vector with the original vector to find another vector?

Comment: @M.Chen What do you mean? If you have 2 perpendicular vector in a 2 dimensional space, you can express all of the vectors in the space as the linear combinaton of the 2 vector. (of course if none of the 2 vectors are the 0 vector)